# If you lose your Bitcoin wallet Password, can you simply transfer private key to another bitcoin wallet provider?

Tags: wallet, private-key, cryptography

If you lose your Bitcoin wallet password, can you simply transfer private key to another bitcoin wallet provider?  I mean if I lost the password to the website where the wallet is stored, can I simply use the private key on a different wallet provider, and gain access to all the coins again?  Or, is the private key tied permanently to a certain wallet provider?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. For standard addresses, the key should be sufficient to identify the funds you can spend and to spend them.
For more complex scripts the private key can be insufficient to rediscover the funds, if you don't have the means to reconstruct the script without information from your account.

Comment: What do you mean by scripts?  And how exactly do people recover the persons wallet, if they lost their password?  I mean do they get the wallet.dat or they just brute force?  Or what exactly?